# How to retrieve sticky post in raw sql?

Tags: sql, sticky-post

How I could made a sql query who retrieve all the sticky post in a wordpress database? This is because we use a new app over the old wordpress website database, and I don't know where Wordpress "store" the sticky attribute.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not stored as attribute, but as list of all stickies. Snippet from core:

```
$sticky_posts = get_option('sticky_posts');
```

So look for the option and then use IDs to retrieve posts.

Comment: But inside the database is stored in some form, no? I can't use the php code, because I have only the database, so I only could use sql.

Comment: @Nisanio it's in option, so look in options table (`wp_options` or whatever your db has)

Answer (score 4):

In raw SQL it would look like this:

```
SELECT option_value FROM `wp_options` where option_name = 'sticky_posts'
```

It will return string similar to:

```
a:2:{i:0;i:27935;i:1;i:33322;}
```

Which means that posts with IDs: **27935** and **33322** are "sticky".
If there are no sticky posts the returned string will look as follows:

```
a:0:{}
```

For more details about Wordpress serialized data structure view https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize

Anyway if you are developing custom theme or plugin it's much better to use snippet provided by @Rarst than writing custom queries.